# call the multiple value by different id

Tags: reactjs

Here I am trying to find the multiple value by different id

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    sid: props.idx,
    imagePreviewUrl: null,
    description: '',
    remove: '',
    imagePreviewUrl: '',
}
this.updatevalue = this.updatevalue.bind(this)
}

handleImageChange(e) {
this.props.onImageChange({ image: e.target.files[0] });
console.log('v')

}
handleClick() {
  console.log(this.props.idx)
document.getElementById('fileinput-' + this.props.idx).click();
}

removeItem() {
let remove = '';
if (this.props.idx) {
    this.setState({ remove: remove })
}
}

updatevalue(type, e,id) {
console.log(type)
let obj = {};
obj[type] = e+id;
console.log(obj)
this.props.onChange(obj);
}

showFrom(i) {
console.log(i)
let { imagePreviewUrl } = this.state;
let $imagePreview = null;
if (imagePreviewUrl) {
    $imagePreview = (<img src={imagePreviewUrl} />);
} else {
    $imagePreview = (<div className="previewText text-center">Upload 
Image</div>);
}
if ((i + 1) % 2 === 0) {
    if ((i % 2) != 0) {
        console.log(i)
        return (
            <div className="card-body  d-flex align-items-center">
                <div className="avatar-upload mr-4">
                    <div className="avatar-edit">
                        <label htmlFor="imageUpload"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="avatar-preview">
                        <div id={`imagePreview-${i}`} onClick= 
{this.handleClick.bind(this)} onChange={this.handleImageChange.bind(this)}>
                            <input type="file" id={`fileinput-${i}`} multiple 
accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg,.svg" className="hide" />
                            {$imagePreview}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Editor
                    id={'a' + i}
                    className="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    description="<p>This is the initial content of the 
editor</p>"
                    init={{
                        selector: "textarea",  // change this value according 
to your HTML
                        plugins: "textcolor",
                        toolbar: "forecolor backcolor",
                        textcolor_map: [
                            "000000", "Black",
                            "993300", "Burnt orange",
                            "333300", "Dark olive",
                            "003300", "Dark green",
                            "003366", "Dark azure",
                            "000080", "Navy Blue",
                            "333399", "Indigo",
                            "333333", "Very dark gray",
                            "800000", "Maroon",
                            "FF6600", "Orange",
                            "808000", "Olive",
                            "008000", "Green",
                            "008080", "Teal",
                            "0000FF", "Blue",
                            "666699", "Grayish blue",
                            "808080", "Gray",
                            "FF0000", "Red",
                            "FF9900", "Amber",
                            "99CC00", "Yellow green",
                            "339966", "Sea green",
                            "33CCCC", "Turquoise",
                            "3366FF", "Royal blue",
                            "800080", "Purple",
                            "999999", "Medium gray",
                            "FF00FF", "Magenta",
                            "FFCC00", "Gold",
                            "FFFF00", "Yellow",
                            "00FF00", "Lime",
                            "00FFFF", "Aqua",
                            "00CCFF", "Sky blue",
                            "993366", "Red violet",
                            "FFFFFF", "White",
                            "FF99CC", "Pink",
                            "FFCC99", "Peach",
                            "FFFF99", "Light yellow",
                            "CCFFCC", "Pale green",
                            "CCFFFF", "Pale cyan",
                            "99CCFF", "Light sky blue",
                            "CC99FF", "Plum"
                        ]
                    }}
                    value={this.props.description}
                    onEditorChange={this.updatevalue.bind(this, 'descrption ' 
+ i)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
} else {
    console.log("asdasd")
    return (
        <div className="card-body  d-flex align-items-center">
            {console.log(i)}
            <Editor
                className="form-control"
                id={'a' + i}
                type="text"
                init={{
                    selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to 
your HTML
                    plugins: "textcolor",
                    toolbar: "forecolor backcolor",
                    textcolor_map: [
                        "000000", "Black",
                        "993300", "Burnt orange",
                        "333300", "Dark olive",
                        "003300", "Dark green",
                        "003366", "Dark azure",
                        "000080", "Navy Blue",
                        "333399", "Indigo",
                        "333333", "Very dark gray",
                        "800000", "Maroon",
                        "FF6600", "Orange",
                        "808000", "Olive",
                        "008000", "Green",
                        "008080", "Teal",
                        "0000FF", "Blue",
                        "666699", "Grayish blue",
                        "808080", "Gray",
                        "FF0000", "Red",
                        "FF9900", "Amber",
                        "99CC00", "Yellow green",
                        "339966", "Sea green",
                        "33CCCC", "Turquoise",
                        "3366FF", "Royal blue",
                        "800080", "Purple",
                        "999999", "Medium gray",
                        "FF00FF", "Magenta",
                        "FFCC00", "Gold",
                        "FFFF00", "Yellow",
                        "00FF00", "Lime",
                        "00FFFF", "Aqua",
                        "00CCFF", "Sky blue",
                        "993366", "Red violet",
                        "FFFFFF", "White",
                        "FF99CC", "Pink",
                        "FFCC99", "Peach",
                        "FFFF99", "Light yellow",
                        "CCFFCC", "Pale green",
                        "CCFFFF", "Pale cyan",
                        "99CCFF", "Light sky blue",
                        "CC99FF", "Plum"
                    ]
                }}
                value={this.props.description}
                onEditorChange={this.updatevalue.bind(this, 'descr' + i)}
            />
            {console.log(i)}
            <div className="avatar-upload ml-4">
                <div className="avatar-edit">
                    <label htmlFor="imageUpload"></label>
                </div>
                <div className="avatar-preview">
                    <div id={`imagePreview-${this.props.idx}`} onClick= 
  {this.handleClick.bind(this)} onChange={this.handleImageChange.bind(this)}>
                        <input type="file" id={`fileinput-${i}`} multiple 
   accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg,.svg" className="hide" />
                        {$imagePreview}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

render() {
return (
    <div className="card bg-color-9" key={this.props.idx}>
        <div className="card-header">
            <span className="card-header-action btn-close pull-right " 
title=" remove " id={"removeitems"} onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this)}>
                <i className="fa fa-times-rectangle fa-lg font-weight-bold 
text-danger"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        {this.showFrom(this.props.idx)}
    </div>
);
}
```

but the result is

```
descrption 1
{descrption 1: "<p>a</p>undefined"}

descrption 1
{descrption 1: "<p>a</p>undefined"}

descrption 1
{descrption 1: "<p>a</p>undefined"}
```

It call the result in same id which is id: 1 . but i want different result by 
different id for different text editor .And when i click text editor it call two same value by same id which i don't want .i want to call different value by different id at one time . what is the problem in this code????

Comment: You might getting wrong `idx` from props. Did you try to console your props?

Comment: Yes I console my props and my idx is 1 and 2